# What does python embedded in c++ look like in a hex editor?

Tags: python, c++, hex-editors

My question is when you embed python in c++ after you compile the program you get an exe file and that's it right?

I have another question (and this is the reason I signed up is to ask this one) if someone opened my program in a hex editor and I had some python code like "def add(x,y):return(x+y)" would the python code show up in the hex editor as plain english?

Comment: I wanted to add the question that i'm asking is way over my head just so you all know, I was just really curious about the hex-editor thing

Comment: If anything, it would show up as plain python ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of a C program with embedded Python code at https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/embedding.html:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the Python code is present in a plain C static char array, so when you open the executable in editor or hex viewer, it will be visible as is.

But you can encrypt or compress the code, put that compressed version into your source code and decrypt/decompress it in runtime just before you pass it to `PyRun_SimpleString`. That way it would be obfuscated and not easily visible in hex editor. But someone who can use a debugger could still dig the Python code out.

Comment: ...but *don't* think encrypting it etc. is secure in any way. It's just more annoying to read, but not impossible for anyone.

Comment: That's true. When you stop the program at right time then you can just search the program memory, or use a debugger (I've added note about it to the answer)

Comment: Okay thanks that answers my questions. I'm making a text game and only my friends are going to play it but I want to prevent them from cheating...

Comment: @madness Then it's probably ok

Comment: so... how DO you hide the python code? or.. you cant? also I have never heard of a debugger aside from like the debug button in visual studio

Comment: Someday I will be embedding python in C++ not anytime soon, maybe in like a year, I want the python code to be as hidden as compiled C++, is that possible? am I breaking the site rules should I post a new question?

Comment: There are more debuggers than VS :) And, if you don't do anything to hide it, a debugger isn't even necessary, because opening the binary program in a text/hex editor and searching for the Python code is enough. ... If you really want to hide something, you can't give it to the user, instead own some server that the program has to connect to.

Comment: @madness This question has already been asked here, search "Python obfuscation". For example I like the idea that you can move the most sensitive parts of your project from Python to C/C++ compiled code.